# For how many $n\in \{1,...,500\}$ is $n$ a multiple of one or more of $5,6$ or $7$

Tags: combinatorics

> For how many $n\in \{1,...,500\}$ is $n$ a multiple of one or more of $5,6$ or $7$

So I believe I want to find the number of integers in the list divisible by $5,6,$ or $7$ and then subtract the times I double counted the ones which are divisible by more then one.

But I'm not sure how I know how many are divisible by $5,6,7$?

Comment: The number of positive integers divisible by $k$ in the first $n$ positive integers is $$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of integers in range $[1,n]$ divisible by some integer k is equal to:
$$\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}}\rfloor$$

(Those weird brackets are the floor function, which is essentially rounding down to an integer. $\lfloor{1.9}\rfloor = 1$, $\lfloor{87.2}\rfloor=87$.

This is because there is multiple of k every k numbers, which is practically the definition of division. You take the floor of it to avoid counting zero.

So to do this problem you would get

$$\lfloor{\frac{500}{5}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{500}{6}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{500}{7}}\rfloor - $$
$$(\lfloor{\frac{500}{\text{lcm}(5,7)}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{500}{\text{lcm}((5,6)}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{500}{\text{lcm}(6,7)}}\rfloor) +$$
$$(\lfloor{\frac{500}{\text{lcm}(5,6,7)}}\rfloor)$$

Which evaluates to $215$